# How do you determine all places where a method is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a rails app with an index method that seems to be for one use. How can I confirm that it is only being used once/for this one purpose? ie is there a way to find all uses of a particular route or method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is a very dynamic language. Therefore, it's really hard to statically determine all the places where a method is called.

What you can do, assuming your test suite has a good level of coverage, is to add a debug statement in the method and run your test suite.

The debug statement can simply print out the [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) stack trace.

```
pp caller
```

This will be sufficient to show you the method that invoked the incriminated method.